# inline many to many field inside django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model that has a many-to-many relationship with another model.
I want to have the options inline in my question model in my Django admin. That is, stacked inline is not enough for me, because I want to be able to edit all the option fields there, not just a box to add in a more beautiful way.

```
class Option(models.Model):
    ...
        

class Question(models.Model):
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option)
```

i use TabularInline and StackerInline but not enough for me.
Also, I used the Django-nested-inline package, but to implement it, it is necessary to have a foreign key relationship from the options to the questions, and I don't want it to be like that.